# Parse FB Login Crash on Function Not Included in Login

Tags: android, facebook, parse-platform, nullpointerexception, facebook-login

I have integrated Parse Login (v1.10.3) and never had this issue  until I integrated FB Login (v4.8.2).  If uninstall and re-install the app and launch, when the app launches I receive an error from an activity that occurs after Login.  I have the MainActivity as the launch page and it checks for a current user.  If the current user is null it redirects to the LoginActivity.  The LoginActivity crashes with a Null Pointer Exception error that occurs in an Adapter linked to a Fragment called from the Main Adapter.  Why is my Login Activity being skipped?

I have a lot of logs in my code as I was trying to determine if there is a current user value at some point or if there is any Login function executed that would cause it to skip the Login, but none of it is executed and the current user is always Null (which I expect).

**Login Activity**

```
public static final List<String> mPermissions = new ArrayList<String>() {
    {
        add("public_profile");
        add("email");
        add("gender");
        add("user_birthday");
    }};



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    //set and transition to signup page
    mSignUpTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.signupText);
    mSignUpTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, SignupActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    //set and transition to reset password page
    mResetPasswordText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.login_ForgotPasswordText);
    mResetPasswordText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, ResetPasswordActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    //set and handle all login tasks
    mUsername = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.usernameField);
    mPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.passwordField);
    mLoginButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.loginButton);

    //Facebook login
    loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile, email, user_birthday, user_friends"));

    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();


    mFbProfile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
    Log.d("Login FB", String.valueOf(mFbProfile));


    // Other app specific specialization

    // Callback registration
    loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            ParseFacebookUtils.logInWithReadPermissionsInBackground(LoginActivity.this, mPermissions, new LogInCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException err) {

                    if (user == null) {
                        Log.d("Login", "Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.");
                        if (err != null) {
                            Log.d("ParseFacebookLogin", "Error: " + err.getLocalizedMessage());
                        }
                    }
                    else if (user.isNew()) {
                        Log.d("Login", "User signed up and logged in through Facebook!");
                        getUserDetailsFromFB();

                        //success
                        FlokkApp.updateParseInstallation(user);

                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                        startActivity(intent);

                        Log.d("Login FB", "User logged in through Facebook!");

                    }
                    else {
                        Log.d("Login", "User logged in through Facebook!");
                        getUserDetailsFromParse();

                        //success
                        FlokkApp.updateParseInstallation(user);

                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
            });

        }
    });





    //Regular Parse Login ----------------------------------------------------------
    mLoginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String username = mUsername.getText().toString();
            String password = mPassword.getText().toString();

            username = username.trim();
            password = password.trim();

            //noinspection StatementWithEmptyBody
            if (username.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty()){
                // display message if field is blank
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);
                builder.setMessage(R.string.login_error_message)
                        .setTitle(R.string.login_error_title)
                        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                dialog.show();
            }
            else {
                // login user
                ParseUser.logInInBackground(username, password, new LogInCallback() {
                    public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
                        if (user != null) {
                            //success
                            FlokkApp.updateParseInstallation(user);

                            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            //Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Successful Login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        else {
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);
                            builder.setMessage(e.getMessage())
                                    .setTitle(R.string.login_error_title)
                                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                            dialog.show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

        }
    });
}

//Facebook login required below ------------------------------------
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.d("Login", "on activity result");

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    ParseFacebookUtils.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

//Facebook save new user code -----------------------------------------------
private void saveNewUser() {
    Log.d("Login", "Save new user");


    parseUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
    parseUser.setUsername(name);
    parseUser.setEmail(email);

    //will need to update once I figure out how facebook sends the data
    boolean genderValue;

    if (gender == "Male") {
        genderValue = true;
    } else {
        genderValue = false;
    };
    parseUser.put(ParseConstants.KEY_GENDERMALE, genderValue);

    String searchtext = name.toLowerCase().trim();
    parseUser.put(ParseConstants.KEY_SEARCHTEXT, searchtext);


    //Saving profile photo as a ParseFile
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    Bitmap bitmap = null; //((BitmapDrawable) mProfileImage.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

    if (bitmap != null) {
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, stream);
        byte[] data = stream.toByteArray();
        String thumbName = parseUser.getUsername().replaceAll("\\s+", "");
        final ParseFile parseFile = new ParseFile(thumbName + "_android_FBLogin.jpg", data);

        parseFile.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                parseUser.put(ParseConstants.KEY_PROFILEPIC, parseFile);

                //Finally save all the user details
                parseUser.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "New user:" + name + " Signed up", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

            }
        });
    }

}

private void getUserDetailsFromFB() {
    Log.d("Login", "getUserDetails From FB");

    // Suggested by https://disqus.com/by/dominiquecanlas/
    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putString("fields", "email,name,gender,picture");


    new GraphRequest(
            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
            "/me",
            parameters,
            HttpMethod.GET,
            new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                    /* handle the result */
                    try {

                        Log.d("Response", response.getRawResponse());

                        email = response.getJSONObject().getString("email");
                        //mEmailID.setText(email);

                        name = response.getJSONObject().getString("name");
                        mUsername.setText(name);

                        gender = response.getJSONObject().getString("gender");

                        JSONObject picture = response.getJSONObject().getJSONObject("picture");
                        JSONObject data = picture.getJSONObject("data");

                        //  Returns a 50x50 profile picture
                        String pictureUrl = data.getString("url");

                        Log.d("Profile pic", "url: " + pictureUrl);

                        new ProfilePhotoAsync(pictureUrl).execute();

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
    ).executeAsync();

}

private void getUserDetailsFromParse() {
    Log.d(" Login", "getUserDetails From parse");

    parseUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();

    //Fetch profile photo
    try {
        ParseFile parseFile = parseUser.getParseFile(ParseConstants.KEY_PROFILEPIC);
        byte[] data = parseFile.getData();
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
        //mProfileImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //mEmailID.setText(parseUser.getEmail());
    mUsername.setText(parseUser.getUsername());

    //Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Welcome back " + mUsername.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_login, menu);
    return true;
}

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


//Required for facebook
class ProfilePhotoAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    public Bitmap bitmap;
    String url;

    public ProfilePhotoAsync(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // Fetching data from URI and storing in bitmap
        bitmap = DownloadImageBitmap(url);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        //mProfileImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        saveNewUser();
    }
}

public static Bitmap DownloadImageBitmap(String url) {
    Bitmap bm = null;
    try {
        URL aURL = new URL(url);
        URLConnection conn = aURL.openConnection();
        conn.connect();
        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
        bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
        bis.close();
        is.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("IMAGE", "Error getting bitmap", e);
    }
    return bm;
}
```

**Main Activity**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpened(getIntent());

    ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
    if (currentUser == null) {
        navigateToLogin();
        Log.d("Login Check", String.valueOf(ParseUser.getCurrentUser()));

    }
    else {
    }

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
    mTabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    mTabs.setDistributeEvenly(true);
    mTabs.setViewPager(mPager);



    try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                "com.myflokk.testflokkd",
                PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
        }
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

    }


}

//included onResume as a part of facebook integration
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // Logs 'install' and 'app activate' App Events.
    AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
}

//included onPause as a part of facebook integration
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    // Logs 'app deactivate' App Event.
    AppEventsLogger.deactivateApp(this);
}



private void navigateToLogin() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement

    switch (id) {

        case R.id.addEvent:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, AddEventActivity.class));
            break;

        case R.id.editProfile:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, UserProfileEditActivity.class));
            break;

        case R.id.action_logout:
            ParseUser.logOut();
            navigateToLogin();
            break;


    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
    if (currentUser == null) {
        navigateToLogin();
        Log.d("Login Check 2", String.valueOf(ParseUser.getCurrentUser()));

    }
    else {
    }

    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    client.connect();
    Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
            Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
            "Main Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
            // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
            // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
            // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
            Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
            // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app deep link URI is correct.
            Uri.parse("android-app://com.myflokk.testflokkd/http/host/path")
    );
    AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, viewAction);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
            Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
            "Main Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
            // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
            // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
            // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
            Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
            // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app deep link URI is correct.
            Uri.parse("android-app://com.myflokk.testflokkd/http/host/path")
    );
    AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, viewAction);
    client.disconnect();
}


class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    String[] tabs;

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        tabs = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tabs);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new UserEventListFragment();
            case 1:
                return new UserSearchFragment();
            case 2:
                return new UserProfileActivityFragment();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return tabs[position];
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }
}
```

**Event Adapter that Causes the Error**

```
protected Context mContext;
protected List<ParseObject> mEvents;
private SimpleDateFormat mFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("E, MMM d", Locale.US);
protected Date mDate;
protected List<Object> mLikeList = new ArrayList<>();
protected int mLikes = 0;
protected String Flokking = "I am flokking to this event!";

public EventAdapter(Context context, List<ParseObject> events) {
    super(context, R.layout.row_event_list, events);
    mContext = context;
    mEvents = events;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {

        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.row_event_list, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.eventName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.eventRow_TextEventName);
        holder.eventLocation = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.eventRow_TextEventLocation);
        holder.eventImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.eventRow_EventImage);
        holder.eventDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.eventRow_Date);
        holder.eventNotLiked = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.eventRow_ImageNotLiked);
        holder.eventLiked = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.eventRow_ImageLiked);
        holder.eventFlokkingCount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.eventRow_FlokkingCount);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }


    ParseObject event = mEvents.get(position);
    ParseObject details = mEvents.get(position);
    final String currentEvent = details.getObjectId();

    //Log.d("EventAdapter", "This is the position --> " + position);

    holder.eventName.setText(event.getString(ParseConstants.KEY_EVENTNAME));
    holder.eventLocation.setText(event.getString(ParseConstants.KEY_EVENTVENUE));
    holder.eventFlokkingCount.setText(event.getNumber(ParseConstants.EVENT_LIKECOUNT).toString());

    //get the date and assign to mDate and then change the way the date is displayed
    mDate = event.getDate(ParseConstants.KEY_EVENTDATE);
    holder.eventDate.setText(mFormat.format(mDate));


    mLikeList = event.getList(ParseConstants.EVENT_LIKES);
    Log.d("Login Event Check", String.valueOf(ParseUser.getCurrentUser()));

    if (mLikeList == null || mLikeList.isEmpty()) {
        //this is false and the user has not liked the event
        holder.eventLiked.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        holder.eventNotLiked.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    else {
        //if there are users in the list check for the current user

        if (mLikeList.contains(ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId())) {
            // true
            holder.eventLiked.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.eventNotLiked.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        else {
            holder.eventLiked.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            holder.eventNotLiked.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
```

**Error Log**

```
02-01 19:05:28.800 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                     Process: com.myflokk.testflokkd, PID: 1933
                                     java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.parse.ParseUser.getObjectId()' on a null object reference
                                         at com.myflokk.testflokkd.Adapters.EventAdapter.getView(EventAdapter.java:98)
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you're aware but parse is winding down their service. That may explain the error but not sure. Check their site they provide some transition docs as well.

Comment: @YoungCoconutCode thanks for the response, but yes I am aware of that and no, that has nothing to do with my error. Thanks